# How do I not save data in my reduce() function in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

In MongoDB, I am trying to write Map-Reduce functions that only saves data if it meets certain criteria.

I cannot figure out how to *not* emit() from my reducer. It always saves the data, one way or another.

Here is a generic example. Ignore the context of the data -- I created this data and code solely for the purpose of this question.

Data Set:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52583b3a58da9769dda48853"), "date" : "01-01-2013", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52583b3d58da9769dda48854"), "date" : "01-01-2013", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52583b4258da9769dda48855"), "date" : "01-02-2013", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52583b4f58da9769dda48856"), "date" : "01-03-2013", "count" : 4 }
```

Map Function:

```js
// Map all data by (date, count)
var map = function() {
    var key = this.date;
    var value = this.count;
    emit(key, value);
}
```

Reducer that simply ignores unwanted data.

```js
// Only save dates which have count > 2
var reducer = function(date, counts) {
    var sum = Array.sum(counts);
    if (sum > 2) {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Results (Value of 1 was not ignored):

```js
{ "_id" : "01-01-2013", "value" : null }
{ "_id" : "01-02-2013", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "01-03-2013", "value" : 4 }
```

I also added in an empty return statement, but got the same results:

```js
// Only save dates which have count > 2
var reducer = function(date, counts) {
    var sum = Array.sum(counts);
    if (sum > 2) {
        return sum;
    }
    else return;
}
```

What I would like to have happen is only the following data would exist in my output collection after running Map-Reduce. **How can I accomplish this?**

```js
{ "_id" : "01-03-2013", "value" : 4 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run an additional mapReduce operation, with the following functions:

```js
var second_map = function() { 
    if(this.value > 2) {
        emit(this._id, this.value);
    }
}
```

and

```js
var second_reduce = function() {}
```

The reduce function can be empty, because [not having multiple values per key will cause it to not even be called](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) in this case.

So, running the mapReduce like so:

```js
db.map_reduce_example.mapReduce(
    second_map, second_reduce, {out: 'final_mapreduce_result'});
```

will produce the following collection:

```js
> db.final_mapreduce_result.find()
{ "_id" : "01-03-2013", "value" : 4 }
```

Note that if you decide to use this approach, you can remove the `if (sum > 2)` condition from the first reduce function.

Comment: This is clever! I'll have to give it a run to see how quick it is when ran on my real data but it's a pretty good trick to accomplish the goal. Thank you.

Comment: I would not do a map/reduce if you are just looking to filter some results.  Just do a remove after the first map/reduce: db.mroutput.remove( { value : { $lte : 2 } } ).  The remove() will run much faster than a map/reduce.

Comment: @RobMoore You're right; that's a simpler and potentially more efficient solution. I think you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I agree with @w0lf. Rob, you should create an answer. I'm going to give both a simple evaluation to test the speed different and accept accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We need to remember that a reducer can be skipped if there is only 1 emitted value (from the map()) for the key.  We should also not try to filter the results in the reduce since reduce can get called multiple time for the same key (each time with a subset of the emitted values).

The only other option is the finalize method but that will result in the null values not the removal of the entries from the result.

I think the only way to get the result you want is to use the aggregation framework instead of map reduce. The pipeline would look like:

```js
db.test.aggregate( 
   { 
     "$project" : { 
       "_id"   : 0, 
       "date"  : 1, 
       "count" : 1 
     } 
   }, 
   { 
     "$group" : { 
       "_id"   : "$date", 
       "value" : { "$sum" : "$count" } 
     } 
   }, 
   { 
     "$match" : { 
       "value" : { "$gt" : 2 } 
     } 
   } 
);
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "01-03-2013", "value" : 4 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

The only major down side to this approach is the results have to come back inline which limits the size of the results to 16MB.  That will be fixed/remedied in the 2.6 release: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10097

HTH,
Rob.

Comment: The main thing I don't like about the Aggregation framework is the output format. It takes all of the results and stores it into a single object. I definitely appreciate the suggestion, though! And knowing that 16MB limit will be fixed soon is great news too. Thanks!

Comment: 2.5.2 (dev release) already has this implemented - aggregation framework can return back a cursor, or you can specify the output go to a collection.  Considering aggregation framework is A LOT faster than map-reduce, I would encourage you to use it whenever you can.

Comment: In addition, if you have to have this for MapReduce, vote for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2340 which requests this feature.  There are things agg framework can't do that map reduce can, so this is still a useful enhancement.